# Make a sharepoint rich text field read only

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rich text box disabling in sharepoint 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322002/rich-text-box-disabling-in-sharepoint-2007)

Someone please let me know how to make a sharepoint rich text field read only based on some condition using jquery.

Comment: True. But dont be an a**hole downvoting as sone as you see a dp.

Comment: @Josh - You really should not add the *possible duplicate* header manually. When (or if) the question is closed, it will be added.

Comment: @Kobi I thought I had seen people add it manually in the past so I did here as well. I did not realize the system did it automatically. Now I know. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Janet, the answer to the duplicate doesn't give you a jQuery answer to your question.

A jQuery solution I have used is hide the input control and display its value as text. That would look a little like this:

```
var txtValue = $("input[title='MyTitle']").val();
$("input[title='MyTitle']").hide().after(txtValue);
```

Comment: That's about the idea, I've done similar things in the past. Two comments though: **1.** It is different for a rich text editor - I doubt a rich text editor is an `<input>`, or even a `<textarea>`. **2.** Using `after` like that is open to html injection: http://jsfiddle.net/VGe7z/ - you probably want to use `.text(txtValue)` on a new element.